# Is it possible to use bitmap fonts in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I am trying to use stylish to make  a style for firefox, using

```
 chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
```

as the url, and i am trying to change the font used in the UI. Being a very big fan of the artwiz fonts, i tried to change it to anorexia, and it didnt work. I tried just about every font in artwiz and it didnt work, so i realised that firefox just doesnt like bitmap fonts. Is it possible to use them?

here is my code:

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);
@-moz-document url("chrome://browser/content/browser.xul") {

}

tab
{
  color: black;
  font-family: "anorexia";
}
```

Comment: Firefox doesn't support XUL since 2 or 3 years ago, so answer is no

Comment: @Fabio really? Because when i edit the script to change the font to other things, it works. its just the bitmap fonts that dont work.

Comment: Sorry, i meant remte XUL (which is what you'll need anyways in real life). You might be using it, but you need to whitelist it yourself, see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Remote_XUL) for reference